# HTML code not working the <br> line

Tags: javascript, html

This seems to work for everyone but me; no matter what I try it says there is a line break error on

```
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA"<br>";
```

that line i've tried all the options but I don't see it working  at all.

Any help would be great; thanks.

Comment: What this line is suppose to do?

Comment: **Also** confused by what that line is suppose to do....

Comment: fix your code, seems like too many quotes

Comment: @vrmc that is also incorrect. If you want to add a string to the end of a variable you need the `+`. The only time you can get away with not having it is if that variable is the start/end of the string.

Comment: test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA"<br>"; Sorry this is the code fully its supose to be an option for a quiz

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA"<br>";
```

Is not valid Javascript.

Did you mean:

```
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA + "<br>";
```

Notice the `+` between chA and `"<br>";`

---

If you ever have errors like this, run them through a [**Javascript lint**](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php). That will give you the precise location of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `+` to the end of chA.

If you want to add a string to the end of a variable you need the `+`. The only time you can get away with not having it is if that variable is the start/end of the string

**[For more help Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_variables_add_strings)**

---

```
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA+"<br>";
```

Comment: that link has too much general information for this question

Comment: @CodeGodie That link is to a page 'javascript tutorials' website, we call that learning the basics.

Comment: Nope. Try this one: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_variables_add_strings

Comment: @CodeGodie Removed all links, main thing is this person got their answer but i will update the answer using the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use + between chA and 
 to concatenate the statement,